# Spring Maven deployed successfully uinsg Intellij to JBoss, but JBoss welcome page is still showing

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, jboss

This is my first ever Spring/maven/JBoss App. Basically, I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

I am using Intellij 2016.3.5, JBoss EAP 7.0.0

I tried to follow the instructions in the home page. I generated the war file following the steps below:

- File => Project Structure
- Artifacts => + => Web Application Archive
- Create Manifest File which looked empty:

[image]

- run successfully.
- In the output it shows it connected to the server

[image]

- it opens automatically the web page at http://localhost:8080. But it is still displaying the Jboss's welcome page.

[image]

- The unnamed.war file is placed in ..\EAP-7.0.0\
- At the end of there is the following added automatically:

> ```
> <deployments>
>     <deployment name="unnamed.war" runtime-name="unnamed.war">
>         <fs-archive path="C:\Users\VAIO\EAP-7.0.0\unnamed.war"/>
>     </deployment>
> </deployments>
> ```

What could have gone wrong in my steps above?

**Update**
After @CrazyCoder 's comment, I followed the documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-web-application-deployment.html), and enabled web Application, where the project modules looks like this now:

[image]

and the project structure:

[image]

It runs, and opens http://localhost:8080/unnamed/
But it displays the word `forbidden` now. Am I heading in the wrong direction?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-web-application.html. You need to specify the context when deploying in the app server Run/Debug configuration, Deployment tab.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you. I tried to follow, and I updated my post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution based on @CrazyCoder's comment. In a nutshell, I followed the documentation as follows

- Download zip from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/)
- Extracted `initial` folder from here (initial directory contains the project that I started with).
- Import `initial` project to Intellij.
- In Intellij, right click on the root project directory, and select `Add Framework support ...`. Then select the Web Application check box in the dialog that opens. What we did here, is to enabling Web Application options as per the documentations [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/enabling-web-application-support.html)
- Verify that Intellij has generated WEB-INF directory under your root project directory, and this directory contains the exploded war file. It does that automatically once you enable your Web Application option. Check [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-web-application-deployment.html) for more details.
- Back to Spring tutorial [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). Create new class `hello/SampleController.java`, and modify the `pom.xml` accordingly.
- Intellij will prompt you to import the changes (if you did not enable auto import) to resolve the dependencies you modified in `pom.xml`. Import the changes
- Assuming your JBoss is installed and configured, you do not need to do anything on the web server side. Intellij will handle that for you.
- Choose `run`, then `edit configuration`, then choose your server (JBoss local in my case)
- If all goes well, it will open the browser with empty page (or pages contains `$ENDED$`, as we did not add any content.
- You can add static content to your html page `index.jsp` in my case, and change the body, and the title, then deploy again to display `Hello World`
- You could eventually bind the returned value from `hello/SampleController.java` to your index page to display dynamic values.